# Not found mongoexport in MongoDB 4.4.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: mongodb

I'm a newbie, I am currently using MongoDB version 4.4.0 but can't find mongoexport file in this version, is there any way to export users.js data?, I have accessed the " usr/bin/ " directory and I found only mongod and mongo files, but not found mongoexport.

help me please, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

These are now packaged up in the MongoDB Database Tools, which can be downloaded from the MongoDB download website.

[image]

https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use the [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/) command if you follow the [installation instruction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

```sh
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

The package `mongodb-org-tools` is part of the `mongodb-org` package.

Comment: I downloaded the deb package from the homepage and installed :)), since I'm new to the terminal command